# Complexity of k-clique for hypergraphs

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, matrices, clique, fixed-parameter-tractable

**Classic Problem:**

Let a number $k$ be given.  The $k$-clique problem is as follows.

Given a graph $G$, does there exist a subset $S$ of $k$ vertices so that any two vertices of $S$ are adjacent?

**Hypergraph Problem:**

Let numbers $c$ and $k$ be given.  The $(c,k)$-hyperclique problem is as follows.

Given a $c$-uniform hypergraph $H$, does there exist a set $S$ of $k$ vertices so that any subset of $c$ vertices from $S$ forms a hyperedge.

**Questions:**

(1) What is the best known algorithm for solving $(c,k)$-hyperclique?

(2) What is its time complexity?

(3) Is there any connection between $(c,k)$-hyperclique and matrix multiplication?

For all I know, this might be a well studied problem.  Any references that investigate this problem are greatly appreciated.

Comment: May be worth pointing out the obvious: Since we understand the case $c=2$, the problem is NP-complete and not FPT in terms of $c$ (but is FPT in terms of $k$).  Further (still obvious), you could rephrase the problem as the selection of $k$ rows of the incidence matrix such that in the submatrix on these rows, $k\choose c$ columns have sum $c$.

Comment: This is usually phrased in terms of finding a $k$-independent set in a $c$-uniform hypergraph.  See Yuster's 2006 paper http://research.haifa.ac.il/~raphy/papers/counthyper.pdf for some useful pointers (including links with matrix multiplication).

Comment: @AndrewD.King, I don't understand what do you mean by "but is FPT in terms of k", k-clique is W[1]-hard in terms of k. And OP: K-Clique is already w[1]hard, but your question is not well research level question, as compares it with polynomial problems.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'm most interested in whether or not there is some $c>2$ and $k>2$ such that $(c,k)$-hyperclique is in $\mathrm{DTIME}(n^{k-\epsilon})$.  We know that for $k>2$, $k$-clique can be solved in $\mathrm{DTIME}(n^{k-\epsilon})$.

Comment: So you know there is no n^o(k) for clique and by relation to matrix multipulation you don't mean a p reduction but only reducing running time, now it's more clear for me, I have no idea about it but maybe you need to include c into the exponent as well.

Comment: Saeed thank you for pointing out my silly mistake -- $n^k$ is not good enough.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not known if there is an $\varepsilon > 0$, $c > 2$, and $k > c$ such that $(c,k)$ hyperclique is in $n^{k-\varepsilon}$ time. Note that the case of $k \leq c$ is trivial. For years I have communicated this problem to many people, and taught it in cs266 at Stanford, due to its connection to solving $k$-Sat. (Several open problem sessions at workshops probably recorded this.)  Here are a few things I know:

I proved several years ago that solving $4-cycle$ on $n$ node graphs in $n^{2-\varepsilon}$ time implies $(3,4)$ hyperclique in $n^{4-\varepsilon}$ time. Haven't published it.

**UPDATE (Aug 2019)** the aforementioned result and some generalizations now appear in the paper

Andrea Lincoln, Virginia Vassilevska Williams, R. Ryan Williams:
[Tight Hardness for Shortest Cycles and Paths in Sparse Graphs](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rrw/SparseGraphsShort.pdf). SODA 2018: 1236-1252

If you can solve $(3,4)$ hyperclique as indicated above, then Max-3-Sat can be solved in strictly less than $2^n$ time. Similarly, solving $(k,k+1)$ hyperclique would yield a faster $k$-Sat algorithm. So if you believe Strong ETH then there is an obvious limit here. The reduction is a natural generalization of the reduction from Max-2-Sat to triangle finding ($(2,3)$ clique) from ICALP'04 and my PhD thesis.

You can solve $(c,k)$ hyperclique in $n^k/(\log n)^{\Omega(k)}$ time by generalizing the paper [Efficient Algorithms for Clique Problems](http://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/combclique-ipl-g.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Ryan!  I appreciate your answer and sharing the paper on the clique problem.  :)

Comment: Is 5-cycle any harder than 4-cycle?

Comment: As far as we know, 3-cycle is harder. The odd case in general takes about O(n^{2.373}) time, the even case takes O(n^2) for fixed length cycles. See for example, Yuster and Zwick, Finding even cycles even faster.

Comment: Oh, wow!  That's quite interesting.  Ok, thank you.  :)

Comment: Cool!  Thanks for the updated reference.